# Tensorflow on Amazon SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, model, amazon-sagemaker, object-detection-api

I need to deploy a custom object detection model using tensorflow AWS API following this tutoriel : https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-tensorflow-object-detection-api
I'm getting this error whenever I try to deploy using this code :

```
predictor = model_endpoint.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m5.large')
```

The problem:

> update_endpoint is a no-op in sagemaker>=2.

Can you help me to solve this please ?
Or can you tell me how to deploy a custom detection model on sagemaker ?

Comment: What version of Sagemaker are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 2.70.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `model_endpoint.update_endpoint(...)`? Alternatively, you can find examples here for deploying a Tensorflow model - https://github.com/RamVegiraju/SageMaker-Deployment/tree/master/RealTime/Script-Mode/TensorFlow.

Comment: I've tried model_endpoint.update_endpoint(...) but it returns an error

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v2.html#deprecations):

> The update_endpoint argument in deploy() methods for estimators and
> models is now a no-op. Please use
> sagemaker.predictor.Predictor.update_endpoint() instead.

However, I recently successfully deployed a TensorFlow 2.7.0 model with SageMaker 2.70.0, as far as I know this is a warning not a breaking-change error.

The errors that you have will have to do with other problems, not this one (bear in mind that it is a warning, not a breaking change, as of the time of this comment + versions of the dependencies).

Comment: Can you please send me the tutoriel you have followed ?

Comment: There is no tutorial per say, I tried on my own and looked in the hyperlink I showed you :https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v2.html#deprecations

Comment: Did you solve your problem? @sinaanis